# Data Migration Tool - /app/etc/local.xml not have crypt key!

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration

I have a problem for magento migration 1.9.2.1 to 2.3.3..

I need the magento 1.9.2.1 encryption key, but my app/etc/local.xml not contain key string! It's just don't have the line! How it is possible?

Have another place the key is stored? Or an option for regenerate this key?4

My local.xml looks like :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Wed, 27 Oct 2010 00:48:54 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[xxxxxx]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[xxxxxxx]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[xxxxx]]></dbname>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
     </global>
     <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
     </admin>
</config>
```

Anyone know how I can solve this?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :-** On the Admin menu, select `System > Manage Encryption Key`.

**Step 2 :-** To generate a new key, set `Auto-generate a Key` to `Yes`

**Step 2 :-** Click the `Change Encryption Key` button

Comment: I don't have this menu option..

Comment: I need the Magento 1.9 key for data migration tool